# Running Qt application built for Linux, on windows

Tags: linux, windows, qt, qt4, qmake

I have a Qt application which I built on Linux. I would like to run the same application on Windows. Is it possible? If yes, how? The Qt application software that I downloaded and used, is version 4.7.4.

Comment: If you insist on not rebuilding it for Windows (which you could do by cross-compiling it on Linux!), you need to run a virtual machine on Windows with a Linux in it.

Comment: Explain more. If you mean, *same* binary, then no, you need Linux with compatible libs (but you can run *that* in a VM under Windows host of course as many have said). If you mean, compile a different binary for Windows, then maybe very easy, maybe not easy at all, depends on the code how much adaptation is needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible? If yes, how?

Yes, it is possible if the application is cross-compiled for Windows target on Linux.

You would need to have the mingw compiler installed on the Linux box when building the application for Windows. You would also need to make sure to use the proper `-mkspec- option for qmake.

If this is missed while building the application on Linux, it is probably not cross-compiling, so you would not be able to run the code on Windows off-hand unless you have a virtual machine installed for Linux, in which case you could do it, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Windows alongside your Linux and install VS2010 and Qt 4.8.* libraries for windows and compile your project there. You may need to make some changes to your source code in order to be compatible with Qt 4.8.* .

Comment: Install VS2010 on Linux? Can you please provide reference to that? Or you mean he could drop Linux? Then, I suggest to re-read the intent.